# How do I search for and delete just the endings of list of directories using 'sed' command?

Tags: sed, batch-rename

How do I use sed to delete just the '-bak' portion of the following list of directory names:

```
accesscode-bak
adminconsole-bak
adoptimizer-bak
ads-bak
ahcms2-bak
alerts-bak
alfresco-bak
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this, assuming that the file `list` contains your directory list:

```
sed 's/-bak$//g' list
```

It removes all ending`-bak` parts and gives that output:

```
accesscode
adminconsole
adoptimizer
ads
ahcms2
alerts
alfresco
```